# is_category function for custom taxonomy's terms

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type, categories

I'm trying to find a conditional tag for recognizing the opened term of custom taxonomy. Let's say I have a taxonomy "map" and I'm browsing the taxonomy's term called 'USA' with ID 50. Is there something like deprecated `is_term`?

Like:

```
<?php if(is_term(50, 'map')) : ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_term mentions that `is_term` was replaced by `term_exists`

Comment: Yes, it was... It wasn't a conditional tag to test if you're on a certain term page or not.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax), for this.

Here is the code:

```
//@param $taxonomy
//@param $term
if (is_tax('map', '50'))
{
    //DO your stuff.
}
```

**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!